# Store and retrieve friends contact list using mysql

Tags: mysql, database, hierarchical

I want to create a database that can store the friends contact list as like social networking
what is the best way to design the database structure and easy to retrieve the contacts of friends using mysql.

I need solution for this, HELP ME

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with hierarchical database structures.  Though please correct me if I missed something.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to model heriarchical data depends on what operations you need to support. I would suggest that you read Bill Karwin's slides [Models for heirarchical data](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data) for a comparison. See in particular slide 48 where there is a summary of the strengths and weaknesses of each approach.

However, I wouldn't regard friendship as a heirarchical structure. There will normally be loops: A is friends with B, B is friends with C, and C is friends with A. Instead you can create a contact table with two columns: user_id and friend_id which are foreign keys into the "users" table:

```
contact_list
------------------
user_id  friend_id
------------------
1        2
2        3
3        1
```

To retrieve the contact list for a specific user id run this query:

```
SELECT friend_id
FROM contact_list
WHERE user_id = 1
```

Here I'm assuming that A being on B's contact list does not imply that B is also on A's contact list.

Comment: Karwin's [SQL-Antipatterns](http://pragprog.com/titles/bksqla/sql-antipatterns) book is excellent reading. Strongly recommended.

Comment: Thank you.. One more thing Do you know how to create or design the database using Hash table and Indexing